# Can't Deploy React Ts App to Azure App service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice, react-tsx

I am deploying ReactTs App to Azure App service by Azure Extension of Visual Studio Code.
Although it has been successfully deployed, but at the endpoint of the deploy link,
there is no change (the initial default interface of the App service).
[image]

This is the endpoint of the deploy link:
https://test-appservice-nev.azurewebsites.net/

[image]

At the endpoint provided by kudu (it shows the deployed ReactTS app), the display is correct. I don't understand why is that.
https://test-appservice-nev.scm.azurewebsites.net/wwwroot/

[image]

Comment: Can you try adding this start up command `pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --spa --no-daemon` in General Settings section under configuration of your web app.

Comment: Glad to know that issue got resolved . I have made the above comment as answer. Feel free to 'Accept as Answer' so it can help other community members facing the similar issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post adding the below Startup command customer is able to see the published changes while he is browsing to the web app URL.

```
pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --spa --no-daemon
```

You can refer to this documentation for more information about [React deployment on the app service](https://azureossd.github.io/2022/02/07/React-Deployment-on-App-Service-Linux/index.html).